# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-requests

I have closed my internet connection and want to catch that in code. I have set time out limit but it's not working. I am getting a huge bunch of error messages, that I have not understood.

Can anyone help to understand what these error messages mean?

My python code (simplified):

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

url = 'https://api.github.com'
try:
    resp = requests.get(url=url, timeout=7)
except Timeout:
    print('The request timed out')
else:
    entries = resp.json()
    print(entries)
```

---

Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1cea4779e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1cea4779e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    resp = requests.get(url=url, timeout=7)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1cea4779e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` means that the name resolution is failing for the given domain (`api.github.com`).

Name resolution (DNS in the usual notion) can fail for various reasons. As you have disconnected the internet, the reason is pretty obvious (`Name or service not known`).

`gai` (GetAddressInfo) is actually used by `glibc` to perform the name resolutions, it's part of `glibc` (and `socket` is using that as you can imagine). You can also actually configure it in `/etc/gai.conf`.

Comment: This answer is not really related to the question.

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution is to capture `socket.gaioerror` with `OSError`.

**Documentation info:**

> exception socket.gaierror
>
> A subclass of `OSError`, this exception is raised for address-related errors by `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`. The accompanying value is a pair (error, string) representing an error returned by a library call. string represents the description of error, as returned by the `gai_strerror()` C function. The numeric error value will match one of the EAI_* constants defined in this module.

**Links:**

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError

Answer (score -3):

It means that you are not setting your credencials in your database.
In my case, instead to set credentials, it was set as default False value.

Comment: How is your answer related to this issue? Can you provide some more info?

Comment: This was my problem too. Unfortunately, this question is completely unrelated to our problem, though it results in the same error message (and is the top google result for it).
I had a postgres database connection string I was dynamically building and my host name was unexpectedly not being given a proper value, hence this socket connection error.