# Get error ```gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))``` from certbot

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, debian, certbot

i try to get SSL cert for my site and i am using `certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com -d www.example.com` but get such error  `raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))`, my OS is Debian 8 and i am using nginx and node js on my server, tnks[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.gaierror: \[Errno -2\] Name or service not known | Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234628/socket-gaierror-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known-python)

Comment: may be, i do not know, but with my internet connection everythink is ok, i think problem can be with my DNS, when i write command `cat /etc/resolv.conf` i get only `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error today. Seems to have fixed itself.

This makes me think it was a transient name resolution issue.

The solution seems to be to wait and try again later.